# Firebase hosting trailing slash for specific path

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I would like to redirect https://b6.games/solitaire to https://b6.games/solitaire/.

How I can do that?
Can I set a trailing slash for a specific path?

Note: I'm using `cleanUrls:true` and `https://b6.games/solitaire/` really is  `https://b6.games/solitaire/index.html`.

There is no `https://b6.games/solitaire.html` file but firebase somehow route into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Firebase Hosting, you will need to change your `firebase.json` to include this section:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "trailingSlash" attribute within "hosting"
  // When true, Hosting redirects URLs to add a trailing slash.
  "trailingSlash": true
}
```

Documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_trailing_slashes